# Can possessives in the middle of a word exist?

Tags: possessives, rules, is-it-a-rule

According to one online [dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/s-), the apostrophe-s combination is

> an ending used in writing to represent the possessive morpheme after most singular nouns, some plural nouns, especially those not ending in a letter or combination of letters representing an s or z sound,

Note the opening, "an ending". Does this mean that an apostrophe COULD NOT be a possessive elsewhere? I have been reading up on the words "bridesmaid" and "groomsman" and according to that [same](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bridesmaid) source, the s in the middle is a possessive. ([Other](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bridesmaid) sources make the s an "unetymological [which] began to appear by 1794")

I'm asking a theoretical question -- could the word be written "bride'smaid" (and/or "groom'sman") or is there a hard and fast rule that possessives are only indicated at the end of a word? (I have yet to find other words besides bridesmaid(s) and groomsma(e)n to which this would apply)

Comment: So a bridesmaid's dress becomes _a bride'smaid's dress_ ?

Comment: If you have a bunch of dresses for different events, the store even might stock brides'maids' dresses. I wonder if words can have two possessives, but that's a different question.

Comment: A 'banksman' is someone who, traditionally, stood on top of a bank, to unhook loads from a crane. The term is still used. You might add that to your collection as it must have been 'bank's man' originally. See Wikipedia - banksman.

Comment: @NigelJ I can't find an online etymology that indicates that the S was ever possessive. The man could have been the one on one of the banks of a pit so the S could be a plural. If I get motivated, I'll go look in the OED.

Comment: Every ending is a new beginning, as the saying goes.

Comment: @NigelJ https://imgur.com/a/OycKVAw should be a picture of the OED info. The S just sort of shows up.

Comment: [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bull%27s-eye) has both the open and the hyphenated form for the noun bullseye: << _bull's-eye_ or _bull's eye_ >>. Note that the apostrophe is present in both. In a reversal of the usual pattern, [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bullseye) and [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bullseye) give the closed compound _bullseye_, mercifully dropping the apostrophe.

Comment: You should rather ask whether *its* may be written as it is and whether *Johns* should be as well. You'll find the apostrophe is written mainly to dissambiguate the plural. However, in *police' car* (bad example), *birds' eye* or ... the number is immaterial. Hence, the Number and eventually the genesis are left ambiguous and underspecified.

Comment: . . . .  and then there's 'helmsman'.

Comment: ... cat's paw, cat's-paw and catspaw.

Comment: The quick etymologies I found for helmsman barely mention the s. I'd have to head back to the OED to be sure, but I wonder if the argument could be made that the s is simply to break up the two M sounds (which would beg application to groomsman).

Comment: knight'sbridge?

Comment: . . . .  and why is it not 'bridemaid' as in 'bridegroom' ? ? ?

Comment: Great. Now I'm confused as to why Fenway has the singular Fen but Fensgate uses the plural.

Comment: @NigelJ blame Old English brȳdguma

Answer (score 1):

The heart of your question really comes down to the rules about compound words (not apostrophes per se) since that's the only time you would potentially have a possessive apostrophe in the middle of a word.

Algonquin College has a nice write up about compound rules, which can be found here:
http://plato.algonquincollege.com/applications/guideToGrammar/?page_id=4523

Compound words start out as commonly combined separate words, often evolve into hyphenated words, and eventually become combined into one word. (open form, hyphenated form, and closed form, respectively).

When a possessive open form compound evolves to the hyphenate or closed form, the internal apostrophe is moved to the end to help avoid confusion. Punctuation is supposed to clarify meaning, after all.

~ ~ ~

Just for fun, here's some possible confusion to think about -

An internal possessive apostrophe would be indistguishable from a contraction apostrophe: 
groom'sman = groom + 'sman. I don't know what 'sman might be short for, hopefully someone can think of something!

If the compound word itself was possessive:
bride'smaid's dress could possibly look like the bride's maid dress.

You could even end up with the plural possessive:
groom'smen's suits, and bride'smaids' dresses.

Or for maximal apostrophe use: 
bride'smaids's dresses. ‍♀️